# Play JSON Reads[T]: split a JsArray into multiple subsets

Tags: json, playframework, play-json

I have a JSON structure that contains an array of events. The array is "polymorphic" in the sense that there are three possible event types `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
{
 ...
 "events": [
   { "eventType": "A", ...},
   { "eventType": "B", ...},
   { "eventType": "C", ...},
   ...
 ]
}
```

The three event types **don't have** the same object structure, so I need different `Reads` for them. And apart from that, the target case class of the whole JSON document distinguishes between the events:

```
case class Doc(
   ...,
   aEvents: Seq[EventA],
   bEvents: Seq[EventB],
   cEvents: Seq[EventC],
   ...
)
```

How can I define the internals of `Reads[Doc]` so that the json array `events` is split into three subsets which are mapped to `aEvents`, `bEvents` and `cEvents`?

---

What I tried so far (without being succesful):

First, I defined a `Reads[JsArray]` to transform the original `JsArray` to another `JsArray` that only contains events of a particular type:

```
 def eventReads(eventTypeName: String) = new Reads[JsArray] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[JsArray] = json match {
      case JsArray(seq) =>
        val filtered = seq.filter { jsVal =>
          (jsVal \ "eventType").asOpt[String].contains(eventTypeName)
        }
        JsSuccess(JsArray(filtered))
      case _ => JsError("Must be an array")
    }
  }
```

Then the idea is to use it like this within `Reads[Doc]`:

```
implicit val docReads: Reads[Doc] = (
    ...
    (__ \ "events").read[JsArray](eventReads("A")).andThen... and
    (__ \ "events").read[JsArray](eventReads("B")).andThen... and
    (__ \ "events").read[JsArray](eventReads("C")).andThen... and
    ...
)(Doc.apply _)
```

However, I don't know how to go on from here. I assume the `andThen` part should look something like  this (in case of event a):

```
.andThen[Seq[EventA]](EventA.reads)
```

But that doesn't work since I expect the API to create a `Seq[EventA]` by explicitly passing a `Reads[EventA]` instead of `Reads[Seq[EventA]]`. And apart from that, since I've never got it running, I'm not sure if this whole approach is reasonable in the first place.

**edit:** in case the original `JsArray` contains unknown event types (e.g. `D` and `E`), these types should be ignored and left out from the final result (instead of making the whole `Reads` fail).

Comment: Can you change the json structure? Something like 
`{
 ...,
events: {
  a: [ ... events of type A],
  b: [ ... events of type B],
  c: [ ... events of type C]
}
}`

this should be easier to convert them back using the reads that you already defined

Comment: Another way. Transform 'events' JsArray to Tuple3[Seq[EventA]], Seq[EventB]], Seq[EventC]] and then map result to Doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put implicit `read` for every `Event` type like

```
def eventRead[A](et: String, er: Reads[A]) = (__ \ "eventType").read[String].filter(_ == et).andKeep(er)

implicit val eventARead = eventRead("A", Json.reads[EventA])
implicit val eventBRead = eventRead("B", Json.reads[EventB])
implicit val eventCRead = eventRead("C", Json.reads[EventC])
```

and use Reads[Doc] (folding event list to separate sequences by types and apply result to `Doc`):

```
Reads[Doc] = (__ \ "events").read[List[JsValue]].map(
    _.foldLeft[JsResult[ (Seq[EventA], Seq[EventB], Seq[EventC]) ]]( JsSuccess( (Seq.empty[EventA], Seq.empty[EventB], Seq.empty[EventC]) ) ){
      case (JsSuccess(a, _), v) => 
        (v.validate[EventA].map(e => a.copy(_1 = e +: a._1)) or v.validate[EventB].map(e => a.copy(_2 = e +: a._2)) or v.validate[EventC].map(e => a.copy(_3 = e +: a._3)))      
      case (e, _) => e
    }  
  ).flatMap(p => Reads[Doc]{js => p.map(Doc.tupled)})
```

it will create Doc in one pass through events list

```
JsSuccess(Doc(List(EventA(a)),List(EventB(b2), EventB(b1)),List(EventC(c))),)
```

the source data

```
val json = Json.parse("""{"events": [
                        |   { "eventType": "A", "e": "a"},
                        |   { "eventType": "B", "ev": "b1"},
                        |   { "eventType": "C", "event": "c"},
                        |   { "eventType": "B", "ev": "b2"}
                        | ]
                        |}
                        |""")
case class EventA(e: String)
case class EventB(ev: String)
case class EventC(event: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would model the fact that you store different event types in your JS array as a class hierarchy to keep it type safe.

```
sealed abstract class Event
case class EventA() extends Event
case class EventB() extends Event
case class EventC() extends Event
```

Then you can store all your events in a single collection and use pattern matching later to refine them. For example:

```
case class Doc(events: Seq[Event]) {
    def getEventsA: Seq[EventA] = events.flatMap(_ match {
        case e: EventA => Some(e)
        case _ => None
    })
}

Doc(Seq(EventA(), EventB(), EventC())).getEventsA // res0: Seq[EventA] = List(EventA())
```

For implementing your Reads, Doc will be naturally mapped to the case class, you only need to provide a mapping for Event. Here is what it could look like:

```
implicit val eventReads = new Reads[Event] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Event] = json \ "eventType" match {
        case JsDefined(JsString("A")) => JsSuccess(EventA())
        case JsDefined(JsString("B")) => JsSuccess(EventB())
        case JsDefined(JsString("C")) => JsSuccess(EventC())
        case _ => JsError("???")
    }
}
implicit val docReads = Json.reads[Doc]
```

You can then use it like this:

```
val jsValue = Json.parse("""
 {
  "events": [
    { "eventType": "A"},
    { "eventType": "B"},
    { "eventType": "C"}
  ]
 }
""")
val docJsResults = docReads.reads(jsValue) // docJsResults: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Doc] = JsSuccess(Doc(List(EventA(), EventB(), EventC())),/events)

docJsResults.get.events.length // res1: Int = 3
docJsResults.get.getEventsA // res2: Seq[EventA] = List(EventA())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your `getEventsA` in an easier way: `events.collect{ case a: EventA => a }`

Comment: Another possibility is `events.filter{_.isInstanceOf[EventA]}`.